# Word by word phrase matching

Tags: c, regex, algorithm, string-matching

I need to implement an algorithm in C that makes phrase matching/phrase identification. Specifically, I have a function that runs in a loop and it outputs to screen a word by word string. I put every output word in a buffer.
I also have a file with a set of phrases like that:

*phrase 1: Good morning Mr. **[last name] [first name]** you have **[amount of money]** $ in your account.*

*phrase 2: Member **[last name] [first name]** has chosen **[option]** from the list.*

So the phrases from my set have a known form, there are composed by a fixed part and a dynamic one (between “**[**“ “**]**”). About the dynamic part I only know the number of words that compose it. By example, in phrase 2, the first dynamic part has 2 words and the second dynamic part has one word.

As my buffer is filled with words from function output, I need to determine which phrase from my list matches the buffer.

I need a suggestion regarding algorithm that can be used if there is already such an algorithm, if not, what would be the best way to do this in C?

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? Can you post some code? The phrasing of the question is a little awkward and i'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: If I understand correctly, the only information you have is the number of words that the buffer should contain to match the phrase. Assuming words are strings separated by SPACE, you can just figure out how many words are in the buffer, and find the corresponding phrase. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: I have a function with a loop. At every iteration, a new word is added in buffer. The words are separated by space. So I know the buffer content at every moment of time and also I know the phrases from list, which I'm looking for.

Comment: so can you post some code?

Comment: If the only information you have is the number of words in the "dynamic" parts of your phrases, then you have to check for the number of words in buffer at the end of your loop, and match that with the phrase(s) that have the same number of missing words

Comment: My idea: to put all the phrases from the list in a matrix, storing a word on every field. Then, when the buffer receives the first word, I will iterate over the first column in matrix to search the word from buffer (store only the lines that match). In this way, I will determine which phrases begin with this word. Then, when the buffer receive the second word, I will iterate over the second column only on the lines stored on previous step. Now I will determine which phrases begin with the first two words in buffer. The algorithm will continue until in my matrix will remain a single line.

Comment: I don't have yet, I started to work on it in this morning. I posted here to ask for an idea, I thought maybe there was already a known algorithm to do this. 
i want to know if my idea is ok, I posted here for a conceptual discussion in the first phase, I will return with my code when will be ready.

Comment: then I misunderstood your question. I thought that your buffer contained only the missing words (ie the dynamic parts) of your phrases. Now I understand that the buffer contains the actual phrases, along with the missing words.

Comment: Exactly and I will compare just the static parts.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a jagged array of character pointers like this

```
char *phrase1[] = { "Good", "morning", "Mr.", "", "", "you", "have", "", "$", "in", "your", "account.", NULL };
char *phrase2[] = { "Member", "", "", "has", "chosen", "", "from", "the", "list.", NULL };
char **phrases[] = { phrase1, phrase2, NULL };
```

In each phrase, there are

- words that must be matched exactly, e.g. `"morning"`
- empty strings `""` that mark the location of dynamic items
- `NULL` pointers that mark the end of the phrase

When using the array, `phrases[p][i]` is the i'th word in phrase `p`,
and `phrases[p][i][0]` is the first character in the i'th word in phrase `p`.

Hence, the code to check for a dynamic item is

```
if ( phrases[p][i][0] == '\0' )
    // this is a dynamic item
```

To check for the end of the phrase

```
if ( phrases[p][i] == NULL )
    // this is the end of the phrase
```

Otherwise, to compare the word

```
if ( strcmp( phrases[p][i], word ) == 0 )
    // the word matches
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea, from this point should be ok. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the missing words follow a known `regex` pattern, for instance `[\w\d]+`, you can create a **big** regex in the following form:

```
^(Good morning Mr. [\w\d]+ [\w\d]+ you have [\w\d]+ \$ in your account.)
|(Member [\w\d]+ [\w\d]+ has chosen [\w\d]+ from the list.)
|(...)$
```

Then matching this regex against the input would tell you which subexpression matched, and the index of the subexpression *is* the index of the matched phrase.

This is exactly what `flex` does internally. So another possibility would be to write your matching phrases as regexes in a `flex` file and ask flex to generate the matcher for you.